# Each $x \in \{0,1\}\cup X$ is an [left?] accumulation point of $X\subseteq [0,1]$, then $X$ is dense in $[0,1]$

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a subset of $[0,1]$ such that:

(i) $0$ and $1$ are accumulation points of $X$;

(ii) $\forall x \in X\setminus \{1\}$, there exists a decresing sequence $(x_n)_{n\ge 1}$ in $X$ such that $\lim_n x_n=x$.

Then $X$ is dense in $[0,1]$.

[Edit: the result is wrong, see below]

Comment: $X = (0,1/3) \cup (2/3,1)$?

Comment: I already realized that example while writing the question; one moment, I edit it :)

Comment: Still not necessarily dense, $([0,1/3) \cup (2/3,1]) \cap \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Ok, even your first example works.. It was definitively wrong, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement is not correct. For instance, $X=[0,\frac{1}{3})\cup(\frac{2}{3},1]$ has the given property, but it is not dense in $[0,1]$.

P.S. I would appreciate a warning if you choose to edit your question so that I may edit my answer appropriately.

Comment: I wasn't sure about the edit, that's why I didn't warn you in time